# Why is my Symfony 5 local server showing the HTTP request as text instead of a rendered page?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I just wanted to try out Symfony 5 for my own education, so I followed the instructions [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html).

`symfony check:requirements` shows that I have the requirements needed to run the application (I'm running Windows 10 with php 7.3.4 running via php-cgi.exe)

I created the project by running `symfony new my_project_name` then, as per the instructions, cd into the project directory and run `symfony server:start`

The command line output says

> [OK] Web server listening
>         The Web server is using PHP CGI 7.3.4
>         https://127.0.0.1:8000

But when I open the local IP address at port 8000 in my browser, I see an HTTP request as raw text, not the expected welcome page or even a 404 page.

[image]

Can anyone advise as to why the standard Symfony 5 startup instructions would not be producing the expected output and whether there's something more I need to configure to get the expected output?

Comment: Check debug mode, maybe it's production

Comment: @Dmitry - can you give a little more detail of what you think I should do?

Comment: In .env file check the `APP_ENV`

Comment: For example you can try set: `APP_ENV=dev`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create the application like this: `symfony new my_project_name --full`

Like the documentation page you linked says, `symfony new my_project_name` is for microservices, console applications and APIs. It does not have the packages required to be interpreted from plain text to a web page.

Comment: Awww, dammit, if I just misread the instructions I'm gonna kick myself. I spent ages trying to work out what was happening.

Comment: As per @marwa's answer below, you can get the skeleton version of Symfony to serve HTML as normal simply by installing the debug bundle as follows: symfony composer req debug --dev . I think the problem is that in DEV mode, Symfony assumes that the debug toolbar is present.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you, but after running those commands the problem was solved:

```
$ symfony composer req profiler --dev
$ symfony composer req logger
```

and
    `$ symfony composer req debug --dev`

I think it's just a composer issue.

Comment: Thanks for this. Just 'symfony composer req debug --dev' worked for me. I think the problem is that in DEV mode, Symfony assumes that the debug toolbar is present. Installing it fixes the problem.